# Execution Order Shutdown Windows and GPEDIT.MSC Scripts

Tags: vbscript, shutdown

I have a question regarding the execution order while shutting down/logoff  Windows and the scripts shutdown/logoff in the GPEDIT.MSC.

When I shutdown/logoff will the scripts in the gpedit.msc be executed before Windows closes everything or is it the other way around, that Windows closes every other running process and then starts the script?

Thank you.

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests I found the answer.
Windows **first closes** all running applications and **then starts** the scripts in the GPEDIT.MSC.

Answer (score 0):

Logoff scripts are run in the security context of the user that is logging off.  That is important to remember as their rights are limited accordingly.  As a log off doesn't necessarily require a shutdown, the system is still up and running.  More info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753583%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Shutdown scripts run in the security context of LocalSystem.  They still need the command shell or script host to be running to execute, so the operating system is still running.  To find out exactly what processes are still running, you could try dumping a process list to a text file in a shutdown script.  You can find a little more info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770300%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Hope this helps.